# ESLint moving comments to align with parent, not children

Tags: comments, eslint, rules, spacing

I'm running eslint on a project with some promises, and it has strange rules for pre-comment spacing. A sample file (simplified for readability, with exactly the same syntax) is below:

```js
const myFunction = (myUrl) => {
    // This comment spacing makes sense
    fetch(myUrl)
        .then(response => {
        // This is the first comment whose spacing is broken
            if(response.status === 404) {
            // Another strangely spaced comment
                window.location.reload();
            } else {
            // The last strange comment
                preformSuccessfulAction(myUrl);
            }
        })
        .catch(() => {
            console.error("no internet connection");
        });
}
```

My .eslintrc.json looks like this:

```
{
    "extends": "airbnb",
    "env": {
        "es6": true
    },
    "rules": {
        "indent": ["error", 4, {"SwitchCase": 1, "ignoreComments": false}],
        "spaced-comment": ["error", "always", {"markers": ["TODO"]}]
    },
    "globals": {
        "fetch": true
    }
}
```

I've attempted to fix the files individually and ignore the comment spacing, which does work, but will not ensure consistency across this project. Is there a lint rule which allows for this specific instance of comment alignment?

Comment: Can't see why this would be tagged "promise". Am I missing something?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 fetch returns a promise, and  the promise methods are what's causing this issue, in my understanding.

Comment: Mmm, marginal. It's about code indentation. Do other types of method chain behave the same way, eg jQuery?

Comment: Yes, so I suppose you're right, promises don't need to be a keyword.

Comment: Would the `MemberExpression` have any bearing on the subsequent methods?

Comment: No, `MemberExpression` has no bearing.

Comment: I think it's something you might raise with the authors of eslint. It's basically buggy behaviour and I doubt you can solve it with settings/options.